# how to put elscreen tabs on the top only?

Tags: emacs, elisp, gnu-screen

I'm using [elscreen](https://github.com/knu/elscreen) in my GNU Emacs 24.2.1 
Currently, when i split my window, I have a same tab panel in each half:
[elscreen http://i.zlowiki.ru/121101_0f30ebba.png/800](http://i.zlowiki.ru/121101_0f30ebba.png/800)
Note that the two lower windows have the same tabs as the largest one.

How can I remove these two duplicates, and keep only the top one?

If it is too hard, what another alternative could be used for GNU screen?

Comment: At least you can disable tabs display completely: (setq elscreen-display-tab nil). They aren't very useful and consume space. You can toggle this setting with C-z T. Also, if you change bottom buffers to something different from the top one, tabs disappear.

Comment: To better understand how the `header-line-format` in both `elscreen.el` and `tabbar.el` work, we can evaluate a simple line of code in any buffer:  `(set (make-local-variable 'header-line-format) "Hello World")`.  The original poster has the same buffer displaying in three different windows.  Inasmuch as the `header-line-format` is being used on a per buffer basis, the same buffer logically displays the same `header-line-format`.  A different buffer can display a different `header-line-format`, but the same buffer being displayed in multiple windows cannot.

Comment: How do you change the text color of the back ground?  It looks weak as blue on black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [elscreen-tab](https://github.com/aki-s/elscreen-tab) plugin?

This plugins is created to resolve what you are annoyed with.

You can install via melpa.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to technically do what you asked:

```
(setq elscreen-display-tab nil) ; disable tabs display

;; get-alist was removed somewhere along the line
;; You can try substituting all instances of get-alist with assoc-default
;; instead of using defalias and see if that works; I haven't tried.
(defalias 'get-alist 'assoc-default) ; get-alist is gone

;; Put tabs display in your frame title bar instead.
(defun elscreen-frame-title-update ()
  (when (elscreen-screen-modified-p 'elscreen-frame-title-update)
    (let* ((screen-list (sort (elscreen-get-screen-list) '<))
           (screen-to-name-alist (elscreen-get-screen-to-name-alist))
           (title (concat "| " (mapconcat
                   (lambda (screen)
                     (format "%d%s %s |"
                             screen (elscreen-status-label screen)
                             (get-alist screen screen-to-name-alist)))
                   screen-list " "))))
      (if (fboundp 'set-frame-name)
          (set-frame-name title)
        (setq frame-title-format title)))))

(eval-after-load "elscreen"
  '(add-hook 'elscreen-screen-update-hook 'elscreen-frame-title-update))
```

[image]

I'm sure it's not what you had in mind, but hey, it's at the VERY top now and only at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElscreenSeparateBufferLists modifies the operation of elscreen slightly borrowing from escreen.  It allows the list of tabs to differ on each buffer.